# revert commit or checkin a new commit?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to figure out what is the best practice.

1. I commit and push my file myfile_ver1 and raise a PR
2. Reviewer request to change 2 lines, I did so and did another commit with the fix and push it as myfile_ver2
3. When approved, then only myfile_ver2 gets merged to master.

What should I do to "myfile_ver1"? Should I clear the directory?

4. Or should I revert my first commit and then push the 2nd commit?

Comment: Why do you have two different files at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that (2) was wrong:

> Reviewer request to change 2 lines, I did so and did another commit with the fix and push it as myfile_ver2

There should never have been two files, "myfile_ver1" and "myfile_ver2". That misses the whole point of git! You should have done an add-and-commit and just pushed, i.e. pushed the very same file in the very same branch. The new commit would have been appended to the very same PR and we wouldn't be having this conversation now: the PR gets approved and the branch gets deleted.

Comment: Thanks very much Matt. The reason i ask, because I did a straight commit after fix but my github still has myfile_ver1.

Comment: I don't see what the surprise or the issue is. A git commit is a snapshot of _all your files_. If "myfile_ver1" was one of your files at the time you made the commit, it's in the commit.

Comment: may be I accidentally change the file name or something. Once again, Thanks